# How to make element inside table switch tabs using jquery ui tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

Hi what I'm trying to do is to create a a tabbed paged in which the elements inside the table can also be used to switch to another tab. I was able to make the tab work using jquery ui but the problem is when I click the element inside the table it does not switch to another tab. Here is my code

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Table</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Employee info</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">

       <table>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#tabs-2">ABC123</a></td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#tabs-2">ABC124</a></td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Info about ABC123 When clicked</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: When you ask a question, it's best to include the *specific error*, show any attempts to solve the problem, and show research effort, [among other things](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: there is no error. the tabs at the top works but the elements inside the table does not

Comment: If this is your whole code and there is no error, I would be incredibly surprised. Is there more to your code that you're not showing (keeping in mind that code should be both *minimal* and *verifiable*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your jQuery:

```
$(".tab2").on("click", function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 1);
});
```

Also, change your HTML to this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="tab2">ABC123</a></td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="tab2">ABC124</a></td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)

Comment: it doesnt work. do i have to replace the my jquery code or just add the code you wrote below it?

Comment: Just add it below. You still need your code to enable the jQueryUI tab functionality

Comment: It still doesnt work.. I will try to play around with your code thanks for giving me an idea

Comment: @Onedaynerd No problem. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NightOwlPrgmr/6rLjL3yh/)